# Is SHA1 safe for hashing passwords when used with additional 128bit random salt?

Tags: language-agnostic, cryptography, guid, cryptographic-hash-function

On our website we use random `GUIDs` as salt for calculating user passwords:

```
SHA1("mysecretpassword" + "a7841254-838a-45a0-8427-145e1d92287d")
```

Unique salt is stored in the database for each password hash.

I know that `SHA1` is not very safe anymore, but considering that we add a very long random salt to it, I can barely imagine it can be broken by brute force attack or by rainbow tables.

So, is this method cryptographically safe at the moment for storing password hashes?

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not, because it's far too computationally efficient. A good password hash function is slow, because that makes the attacker's life more difficult.

From a purely cryptographic POV, too, concatenating the salt with the password like this is less secure than using a proper HMAC; for details, see the [Wikipedia HMAC article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac).

Don't try and invent your own password hashing system, there are plenty of good ones around, such as [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) and [pbkdf2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pbkdf2).